# GetElementsByTagName with the class selector

Tags: javascript

I have a question regarding the GetElementsByTagName, i would like to retrieve all elements which are TD but also have class name "MyClass" and which do not have an attribute height.

I do the following:

`document.getElementsByTagName("TD")`

and it works. When i do

`document.getElementsByTagName("TD.MyClass:not[height]")`

it doesn't work

How do I make it possible withouth using JQuery or can i retrieve first all TD's and then apply some filter on the set of td's?

Any help?

Comment: Use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).

Comment: Yeah, I think that `getElementsByTagName` literally just looks for tags and not classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is something you'd use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) for. It's worth noting that you'd need to use brackets around that `:not[height]`, too, otherwise your selector isn't valid:

```
document.querySelectorAll("TD.MyClass:not([height])");
```

Comment: is there another way, cuz it seems not all IE version support this :(

Comment: @Alnedru querySelectorAll [is supported by IE8 onwards](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector). The problem here is that `:not()` [*isn't* supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) by IE8. You'll need to find a different CSS selector which achieves a similar affect on IE8.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `document.querySelectorAll` which returns collection of html nodes that apply to given selector

```
document.querySelectorAll('td.myClass'); // will return array of all tds with given class
```